# how to catch Yii CConsoleApplication warnings which was thrown by native php?

Tags: error-handling, yii

I found that yii console application uses own handler to throw any errors or warnings but i need to catch some warnings or error but i can't.

How i can catch native warnings or errors incide my code ? 
I just want to catch some of warnings and errors, some of them must be handled by Yii errorHandler()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use NetBeans IDE to develop. I've activated XDebug in php.ini. With that in hand I am able to follow up errors, debug my Yii applications, watch variables and so on. [Debugging PHP code](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html#gettingReady).